# GA4 data from Jan 2023 - Aug 2023 is gone even if the data retention is set to 14months

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Anyone can help me with a problem.

I was generating a report in GA4 that would compare January 2024 website visits with January 2023 website visits, but to my surprise, the data is 0. Please take note that I am using the standard report. The data retention was set to 14 months, so I am unsure what is happening.

In the previous month, I have successfully generated a report that compares Dec 2023 with Dec 2022 without a problem. So, I am confused as to why the data is 0 now.

By the way, I set up the GA4 in July 2022, so there should be enough data for a Yearly comparison.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH5aL.png)

The same thing happened to me. I changed the view from Session Primary Default Group (the bottom option) to Session Default Channel Group (the top option) and the data is showing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Adam. That solved my problem. My bad didn't change the channels when I was checking the Report. I didn't know there was a new channel. Thanks a lot for your help.